# Failed to use "rvictl" command to set up an RVI for iOS device

Tags: iphone, macos

I use

```
rvictl -s 36621ee66871bfa671997c023a1b9197ef6a4b37
```

to set up an RVI for my iPhone, but it just return

```
Starting device 36621ee66871bfa671997c023a1b9197ef6a4b37 [FAILED]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try ensuring you don't have a hanging rvictl process with:

`rvictl -x 36621ee66871bfa671997c023a1b9197ef6a4b37`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue on macOS Big Sur 11.5.2 with Xcode 13.2.1 when trying to start an interface for iPhone 12 SW Version 15.2.

After restarting my MacBook twice I was asked to change my Security & Privacy settings by unlocking the settings lock and giving Xcode the requested permissions.

I'm not sure if this really is the cause but for me it worked. It is also possible that I have been prompted to grant the permissions before but did not see it.